# two databases in one system in asp.net core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a system that I work on which already have a database using code first. I had asked to connect my system to other database to get some data from one table in it which is employees table how can I do that.

the two DBs on the same server

After I searched in google i find noting clear.

Comment: how can i connect to an second existing db to read form it only

Comment: So... You are able to successfully connect to a database, and you're asking how to connect to a database?  What exactly is stopping you?

Comment: no i don't know to connect to second db to read from it

Comment: @mamw: But what exactly is stopping you from *trying*?  According to your question you already know how to connect to and read from a database.  So why can't you repeat that process?  It's really not clear what the problem is.  Perhaps you could make an attempt and demonstrate in the question what isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Entity Framework** you able to connect and use data from multiple sources.

I suggest you to create a new context. The context is a **class** that **inherit** from **DbContext**.

You have to provide a new connection string for your "Employee" context.

```cs
//Entity class representation
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

//Entity Framework context
public class SecondContext : DbContext
{
    public SecondContext(DbContextOptions<SecondContext> options) : base (options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

At the end, you will have two contexts in your application.

Comment: thanks for your answer I already do that before asking the question but when do migration the fowling message appears Unable to create an object of type 'SecondDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728